# Redirect different external domains to different subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here's my problem

I have a hosting provider (hostingprovider) and also several different domains that I bought with a different provider (sitea.fr, siteb.fr, www.sitea.fr, www.siteb.fr)

What I would like to achieve is this :

When you request either www.sitea.fr or sitea.fr, point that to hostingprovider/lfr/ **without changing the url**
Same with siteb, but with a different subfolder: siteb.fr->hostingprovider/tac/, www.siteb.fr->hostingprovider/tac/

I can't for the life of me find anything relevant to my problem. At the moment both sitea and siteb point to the root of hostingprovider, but I can't figure out how to make them point to their respective subfolders.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, addon domains solve my problem.